# How do you can you disassemble and dump an entire binary?

Tags: binary-analysis, radare2

It's easy to seek to a particular function and dump it's contents as Assembly language. However, I cannot find an obvious way to immediately disassemble and dump an **entire** binary. I want to use it more like I use IDA and `objdump` by seeing the entire disassembly at once.

Comment: Visual mode actually does what I want for the most part. I'm open to other approaches, though.

Comment: one trick -  `pd $s | less`

Answer (score 13):

You can use the special *"'$' variables"* `$s` to get the size of your binary, and pass it as an argument to the `pd` command to disassemble the whole file:

```
[0x004048bf]> pd $s
Do you want to print 188.0K chars?
```

For more information on *'$' variables* available see `?$?`.

Comment: I usually use `objdump -d binary | less` command, is there anything similar can be done using r2. Just output the highlighted disassembly to stdout?

Comment: Why not using the radare2 shell instead? If you really want to disassemble the whole binary to stdout, you can use `r2 -c 'pi $s'`, but it's much less convenient.

Comment: But it does not highlight the syntax, that is one of the reasons I am using radare2 - to get the highlighted syntax.

Comment: The _radare2_ shell does : `r2 -A ./binary` then `pdf`, and be amazed.

Comment: No, it did not disassemble the whole binary, it just disassembled `_start` function.

Comment: That's the whole point. Most of the time, you're like to _explore_ the binary, to use r2's analysis capabilities, instead of dumping the whole disassembly. You can of course do that inside the shell with `pi $s`.

Comment: Thanks! I have actually tried option `pi $s` which is similar to `objdump -d binary`, but I also want ` | less` part, is there any way to do that in r2?

Comment: You can pipe to `less` in radare2 too.

Comment: I have tried `pi $s | less`, but syntax highligthing is gone.

Comment: @user: You can run radare with `r2 -e scr.pipecolor=true`

Answer (score 3):

If you want more like an Ida experience you could try the GUI project for Radare called Bokken.

https://github.com/radare/bokken

Update: it seems to have been superseded by the [cutter](https://github.com/radareorg/cutter) project.

Comment: Bokken is not really production-ready yet; I wouldn't recommend using it.