# Dumping binary with radare2

Tags: radare2

I have found [the command](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8568/how-do-you-tell-radare-to-do-a-full-dump-of-an-x86-binary) `r2 -c 'pi $s'` to dump a binary with radare2. I have tried this redirecting the output to a file: `r2 -c 'pi $s' binary > dump.txt`. The dump is created but radare2 gets unresponsive. Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you're not passing the `-q` flag to radare2:

```
$ r2 -h | grep -- -q
-q           quiet mode (no prompt) and quit after -i
```

The `-c` flag will execute a command in radare2, and then land you in the radare shell, but since you're redirecting `stdout` to a file, you can't see this. But if you hit `q` (as in `q`uit) and *Enter*, radare2 will exit.

This is the command that you should use: `r2 -q -c 'pi $s' ./a.out > out.txt` if you want radare2 to dump the entire binary, then exit.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest you tried working with OllyDbg and WINE. Kali linux has this combo pre-installed in its toolbox. It works fine in many platforms (ubuntu, open-suse, etc).